# Android fragments activity

Tags: java, android, fragment

I have a small problem.
in my activity i have a button and in my fragment i have textboxes.

Now when i click on the button i want see a dialog with the information of the textboxes.Below you can see my dialog that stands in my activity

```
   public void onFragmentInteraction(Person uri) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("test");
        builder.show();

    }
```

My actionlistener of my button is in my activity and my textboxes are in my fragment. I have tried this with a bundle but this didn't work.

Someone can help me with this ?

Comment: How do you set the listener? The signature of this method is incorrect for a onClick().

Answer (score 0):

If you really **must** keep your button and textviews in seperate activity/components then you'll need to allow some communication between the two.

here's a nice tutorial on how to do this -https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

A really rough way to achieve what you want is to pass text changes from your textview and store them in your activity.

something like -

```
      textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            ((ActivityName)getActivity()).setSomeText(s.toString());

        }
    });
```

in the activity you would then create a matching public method

```
public void setSomeText(String someText) {
    this.someText = someText;
}
```

you can then access "someText" in the activity.

*This should be done through an interface*

Answer (score 0):

You should put the listener in the fragment and set it programmatically in Java rather than in the XML.